# How to merge row with same value in PHPExcel, array looping with if logic

Tags: php, codeigniter, web, phpexcel

I need help for the looping logic in phpexcel, that can merge row with same transaction id

here's the example code

```
foreach ($transaction as $key => $value) {
     // I need if condition for $merge (ex. N4:N5)
     $excel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells($merge);
}
```

i have tried some logic that compare last looping transaction id, with current transaction id. but my logic is still bad and doesnt work well.

I want the result like this

[image: Goal]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following solution was developed using [PHPSpreadSheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet), an upgrade of PHPExcel. However, you should be able to adjust the method to PHPExcel as the logic should be the same.

The main logic is (for every loop):

- Check or mark current invoice code if code is empty
- Set next invoice code, get it from next row's value
- render merge based of the following condition:

  - is current row is equal or greater than start of invoice code's row
  - if prev invoice code is different than next invoice code (or if next invoice code is null (this mark the end of record))
- And finally, render merge using [`mergeCells()`](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/topics/recipes/#mergeunmerge-cells) method:

  ```
  $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells($cellToMerge);
  ```

Full example code:

```
<?php
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

$path = dirname(__FILE__);

$data = array(
    array(1, 'INV201806001', '1000'),
    array(2, 'INV201806001', '1000'),
    array(3, 'INV201806002', '0'),
    array(4, 'INV201807001', '1000'),
    array(5, 'INV201807001', '1000'),
    array(6, 'INV201807001', '1000'),
    array(7, 'INV201807002', '0'),
    array(8, 'INV201807002', '0'),
);

$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

$row = 3;
$startRow = -1;
$previousKey = '';
foreach($data as $index => $value){
    if($startRow == -1){
        $startRow = $row;
        $previousKey = $value[1];
    }
    $sheet->setCellValue('C' . $row, $value[0]);
    $sheet->setCellValue('D' . $row, $value[1]);
    $sheet->setCellValue('E' . $row, $value[2]);
    $nextKey = isset($data[$index+1]) ? $data[$index+1][1] : null;

    if($row >= $startRow && (($previousKey <> $nextKey) || ($nextKey == null))){
        $cellToMerge = 'E'.$startRow.':E'.$row;
        $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells($cellToMerge);
        $startRow = -1;
    }

    $row++;
}

$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
$writer->save('test-xls-merge.xlsx');
```

Here's the screenshot of codes above:

[image]